# How to clear server cache using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, caching, server

I am using GoDaddy server for my flash based web application, my problem is that server is getting slow when I run the Flash application more than 15-20 mins. The reason was found to be the server load caused by my Flash application since it has to communicate too many times (1 time in 100m seconds) with the server. The problem will be solved when I restart the Apache server.

So, now I want to clear the server cache pro-grammatically just by triggering a simple PHP file.
Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I can't think of any form of cache that slow your machine down. Are you sure you need to "clear the server cache"? And if so, what cache do you think you need to clear? Opcode cache?

Comment: yeah, you said it is becoming slow because of the traffic load on the server. I dont think this can be solved by clearing cache rather try some load balancing mechanism.

Comment: I don't know much about server cache and all, My Server is getting slower as I run my application more than 15 mins. I just want to run my application without affecting my server. I welcome any solutions.